# Red5. Disable automatic creation of room

Tags: red5

How I can disable automatic creation of room in Red5?

Thanks,
Cyril

Comment: We have security in-place for play/publish and shared objects, but not this particular feature. I'll see if I can come up with something usable and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as overriding roomStart() in your application adapter class and returning false.

```
@Override
public boolean roomStart(IScope room) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply by not connecting to a room. By default when you connect a client to a scope other than the application root it will create the room instance. Another thing you can do is remove the scope after it creates it on the server.